# Running node behind apache displays page (code) instead of executing page

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu

I have spent many hours reading tutorials and solutions showing how to get node working behind apache using the ProxyPass directive, but when the site is visited, it **displays the page contents** (code) instead of **executing** it.  Here's some background:
- here is my apache vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
        DirectoryIndex app.js
        <proxy>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyRequests off
        <Location /var/www/mysite>
          ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
          ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
        </Location>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- I am loading these modules into Apache: **proxy_module** and **proxy_http_module**.  (I even tried loading proxy_http2_module and that did nothing.)
- For this test, I am running node by loading express: "node app.js".  Here is the code at the bottom of app.js that runs the server:

```
<snip>
//Start server
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

- *When I access the site from the command line on the server using lynx at http://localhost:3000, the site **does load**!*

There doesn't appear to be any information on this - help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to install and use nginx instead and it works.